# Turning an array of objects, into a single object with the same value for all keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am working on a list of optional checkbox elements and want to have a **checkAll** function. With this function I am passing the **rowsArray** as the argument and want to turn it from an array of objects to one single object, with all the options in there with their ids as the key and their value as true.

So from this
**rowsArray** →
`[{name: '0years', id: '0 TO 1'}, {name: '1years', id: '1 TO 2'}{name: '2years', id: '2 TO 3'}, ~~~~~]` (there are 17 objects inside)

to this
`return{ '-1 TO 0': true, '0 TO 1': true,'1 TO 2': true }`

I don't need the **name** value anymore and want to give it a new value of **true**, but am not sure how to add that.

So far I have this, but I am not sure where to go from here:

```
function convertRowsToObject(rowsArray) {
        // rowsArray [{name: '', id: '-1 TO 0'}, {name: '', id: '1 TO 2'}]
        // return an object that looks like
        // { '-1 TO 0': true, '1 TO 2': true }
       let allTrue = Object.assign({}, ...rowsArray)
        console.log(`rowsArray → `, rowsArray)
        return {}
      }
```

This unfortunately only gives me back the final object of the array 17 times...

`allTrue →  {name: '100+ years', id: "100 TO 150"}`

Should I be using reduce here? Removing the name and replacing it with a single value of 'true' is stumping me.

Any ideas on how to progress with this?

Cheers!

Comment: Seems pointless, if you're setting their values to `true` and you know what properties you're going to access.

Comment: This is for a vue component and the `true` value is filling in a prop value; so it certainly has a point. Sorry if my lack of context provided is annoying, but I figured the easiest way to an answer was to take it out of context of the component itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this:

```js
const rowsArray = [{name: '', id: '-1 TO 0'}, {name: '', id: '1 TO 2'}];

function convertRowsToObject(rowsArray) {
  // rowsArray [{name: '', id: '-1 TO 0'}, {name: '', id: '1 TO 2'}]
  // return an object that looks like
  // { '-1 TO 0': true, '1 TO 2': true }
  return rowsArray.reduce((acc, { id }) => ({ ...acc, [id]: true }), {});
}

const result = convertRowsToObject(rowsArray);

console.log(result);
```

Not sure why you need this though, because the `true` value doesn't provide any information, a simple array may be enough:

```js
const rowsArray = [{name: '', id: '-1 TO 0'}, {name: '', id: '1 TO 2'}];

function convertRowsToObject(rowsArray) {
  return rowsArray.map(({ id }) => id);
}

const result = convertRowsToObject(rowsArray);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Honestly, this is just one half of the function, but it was the part I was having the most trouble with. I figured asking the simpliest, abstracted question was the best way to get a response and here we are!

Later in the function I am doing a forEach on all of the `allTrue` elements and emitting them as a payload (vueJS) so the **true** value is actually extremely helpful. Sorry if it seemed like a silly request and I probably should have provided more context, but this actually helped me make it work! Thank you so much!

Comment: I knew there was something else behind that's why I wrote with conditional tense. Glad it helped!

Comment: It definitely did! Do you think in this case that it's worth mentioning the context? I fear that adding too much text and depth makes people just skip questions more often.

Comment: It's worth mentioning the context just with a short sentence, that helps identify [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but your question is still fine